# How to search a string for different types of numbers

Tags: python, string

I have multiple strings that each contain a year and some text. An example of one string is: `"The year is 2004"`. But, another string may look like this `"this was made in 2003.5"`. How would I check many strings like this and extract the correct number?

Comment: First define what you consider a "correct" number. Any 4-digit number? Any 4-digit number in range (1900, 2100)? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` here :

```
>>> str = "The year is 2004"
>>> re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", str)
['2004']

>>> str = "this was made in 2003.5"
>>> re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", str)
['2003.5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions. For example this will get all numbers in a given string:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', 'year is 2004')
['2004']
>>> re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', 'this was made in 2003.5')
['2003.5']
```

You can fine tune the regular expression to fit your definition of "correct" number.

Comment: In your solution this gives me re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', 'the 1st year is 2004') 
`['1', '2004']`

Comment: Yes, it's not clear what the OP wants, so this is one possibility. If you don't want that 1 you could change the regexp to `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b`, but without knowing the exact requirements for OP's problem we can't give an exact regexp.

Answer (score 0):

For your types of numbers also works:

```
def find_number(my_string):
    for element in my_string.split():
        try:
            return int(element)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                return float(element)
            except ValueError:
                pass
my_string = "The year is 2004"
number = find_number(my_string)
```

This will give you the right output for both examples.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension and not using regex

```
def convert(e):
    try:
        return float(e)
    except:
        return None

str = "the 1st year is 2004"
m = [e for e in str.split(" ") if len(e) >= 4 and convert(e)]
print m 
>>> ['2004']
```

As other people mentioned without knowing what is "correct" number it is difficult to give an answer that fits all the use cases. However, I assumed that here right number is something more than 4 digits long